# Bash: Extract reads from BAM files based on read length

Tags: bash, extract, bam

my first question on stack overflow and I hope you can help me.

Suppose a BAM file, from which I only want to extract the reads of a certain length (42 - 65 nt; column 10), but with the information of the remaining columns. Exemplary snippet:

`VH00693:3:AAANGKTM5:1:1507:7438:26974_AGTTATAGAC 256 ENST00000438504.2 352 0 32M * 0 0 CCTGCAGGAATATGGCTCCATCTTCATGGGCG CCCCCCCCCCC;CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC NH:i:50 HI:i:4`

`VH00693:3:AAANGKTM5:1:1507:7438:26974_AGTTATAGAC 256 ENST00000438504.1 352 0 32M * 0 0 CCTGCAGGAATATGGCTCCATCTTCATGGGCGCCTGCAGGAATATGGCTCCATCTTCATGGGCG CCCCCCCCCCC;CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC;CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC NH:i:50 HI:i:4`

My try was to access the BAM file (**Initial.bam**) with samtools view, and to search for substrings fitting to the desired read size, which are parsed into a new BAM file (**Extract.bam**).

`samtools view -h Initial.bam | \awk 'substr($0,1,1)=="@" || ($10>=42 && $10<=65)'| \samtools view -b > Extract.bam`

However, the Extract.bam only contains the extracted header section (starting with '@') of the Initial.bam. So, header extractions works, as well as parsing into a new bam file. The initial files do contain reads of the desired range, but at that point I do not know how to adapt my code snippet.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an adaptation that delivered the desired output.

```bash
samtools view -h Initial.bam | awk '{ if ( substr($0,1,1) == "@" || (length($10) >= 42 && length($10) <= 65)) {print $0} }' | samtools view -b > Extract.bam
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `gawk`, this should work for the others

```
samtools view -h Initial.bam |

mawk '((_=length($10))%__-(_-__)%24)</^[@]/' __=42 | samtools view -b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to use:

```
samtools view -h -e 'length(seq)>=42 && length(seq)<=65' -o Extract.bam Initial.bam
```

Note that you can distinguish between sequence lengths ('seq') and alignment lengths ('rlen' or 'qlen').

See the [SAMtools docs on filter expressions](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools.html#FILTER_EXPRESSIONS) for more info.